# In a box there are 2 yellow,4 blue,7 green balls....

Tags: combinatorics

In a box there are 2 yellow,4 blue,7 green balls.The balls are taken out from the box one by one.In how many ways can we take them out?And in how many of the cases the restriction is true:the balls from the same color are removed one by one?.For the first part I guess simple binomial multiplication but what about part2?

Comment: Are balls of the same colour to be considered identical? If so, there are only $3!$ ways to do the second job: YYBBBBGGGGGGG and the ways obtained by permuting the $3$ letters.

Comment: yes I also thought that is the answer thanks

Comment: You are welcome. What did you get for the first question (unsimplified)?

Comment: I get $\frac{13!}{2!4!7!}$ or equivalently $\binom{13}{2}\binom{11}{4}$.

Comment: $ \binom{13}{2} . \binom{11}{4}.\binom{7}{7} $ yes

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  for the first part imagine the balls are labeled with numbers.  How many ways can you order them?  Now, how many arrangements are the same because the blue balls are interchangeable?  Then yellow and green.....